# Create a DB index if it doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have an Alembic migration which creates a few DB indexes that were missing in a database. Example:

```
op.create_index(op.f('ix_some_index'), 'table_1', ['column_1'], unique=False)
```

However, the migration fails in other environments that already have the index:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "ix_some_index" already exists
```

PostgreSQL supports an `IF NOT EXISTS` option for cases like this, but I don't see any way of invoking it using either Alembic or SQLAlchemy options. Is there a canonical way of checking for an existing index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can pass `if_not_exists` argument to create_index function in Alembic as:

```
op.create_index('ix_some_index', 'table_1', ['column_1'], unique=False, if_not_exists=True)
```

Similarly, for dropping indexes you can use `if_exists` argument as:

```
op.drop_index('ix_some_index', if_exists=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a somewhat blunt solution that works for PostgreSQL. It simply checks whether there's an index with the same name before creating the new index.

Beware that it doesn't verify that the index is in the correct Postgres namespace or any other info that could be relevant. It works in my case because I know there's no other chance of name collision:

```
def index_exists(name):
    connection = op.get_bind()
    result = connection.execute(
        "SELECT exists(SELECT 1 from pg_indexes where indexname = '{}') as ix_exists;"
            .format(name)
    ).first()
    return result.ix_exists

def upgrade():
    if not index_exists('ix_some_index'):
        op.create_index(op.f('ix_some_index'), 'table_1', ['column_1'], unique=False)
```

Comment: It would be better to either use `pg_indexes` instead of `pg_class` (that would also make checking of the correct schema and table easier). When using pg_class, it would be better to use `relkind = 'i'` instead of `reltype = 0`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I've updated the code to use `pg_indexes`.

Comment: @DagHøidahl Appreciate this..long running statements on CI CD pipelines are timing out our ECS containers, this helps a lot